# Confusion matrix ix not giving correct result

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

two types of csv files i.e train.csv(29968 samples ) and test.csv(14980 samples)
both the dataset contain following attributes:
id: unique id for a news article
title: the title of a news article
author: author of the news article
text: the text of the article; could be incomplete
status: a status that marks the article as potentially unreliable
1: Fake
0: real
   program is working fine but not giving appropriate results for confusion matrix.

Comment: Please add more information, like the code and the error.

Comment: there are no errors.confusion matrix should be in 2*2 format but it is giving in 4*4 format

Comment: 9 0 3 0   0 3543 8 0   3 11 3914 0   1 0 0 0 is the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually confusion matrix gives the data for the given test samples. you should get confusion matrix for the test samples(14980 samples) only.